# Optimize code for transforming one datatable into another

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datatable

We're having to transform a datatable into another which involves mostly transposing the source datatable into a different format. 
Thinking of it sequentially, I have implemented it as below:

```
DataTable riskTable;
this.InitializeRmmRiskTable(out riskTable); // Initializes the columns

var calculatedRisk = (from DataRow tradeRow in tradeTableToFilter.Rows
                  where tradeRow["TradeID"] != null
                  select new
                          {
                              ROW_ID = 0,
                              TCN = tradeRow["TradeID"].ToString(),                               
                              CCY = tradeRow["CURRENCY"],                                 
                              USD_VALUE = calculator.Invoke(tradeRow) // configured delegate that will fetch the value
                          }).Distinct();

foreach (var rowData in calculatedRisk)
{
    DataRow rowToAdd = riskTable.NewRow();

    rowToAdd["ROW_ID"] = rowData.ROW_ID;
    rowToAdd["TCN"] = rowData.TCN;
    rowToAdd["CCY"] = rowData.CCY;
    rowToAdd["USD_VALUE"] = rowData.USD_VALUE;

    riskTable.Rows.Add(rowToAdd);
}
return riskTable;
```

Any suggestions to optimize this in terms of memory-footprint and execution cycles?

Comment: Does "don't use `DataTable`" count as a valid solution?

Comment: I'm using this way too, I'm just like you, trying to find another way to optimize this job :)

Comment: @MarcGravell : Yes, it does. Although the return type of the method is a DataTable, I can modify that side if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove a lot of column lookups easily enough:

```
object[] values = new object[4];
foreach (var rowData in calculatedRisk)
{
    values[0] = rowData.ROW_ID;
    values[1] = rowData.TCN;
    values[2] = rowData.CCY;
    values[3] = rowData.USD_VALUE;

    riskTable.Rows.Add(values);
}
```

This assumes you know the order of the columns. Otherwise, the `DataColumn` API is the most direct, so you could store the 4 `DataColumn`s and use those in the indexer. This applies equally to the *reading* code, i.e.

```
var tradeId = tradeTableToFilter.Columns["TradeID"];
var currency = tradeTableToFilter.Columns["CURRENCY"];
```

then:

```
var calculatedRisk = (from DataRow tradeRow in tradeTableToFilter.Rows
    let tradeIdVal = tradeRow[tradeId]
    where tradeIdVal != null
    select new {
        ROW_ID = 0,
        TCN = tradeIdVal.ToString(),                               
        CCY = tradeRow[currency],                                 
        USD_VALUE = calculator.Invoke(tradeRow)
    }).Distinct();
```

etc.

The use of `Distinct` does mean that all the objects will be buffered in memory again; if you know that you need this, fine, but in many cases this may be redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Some tips without changing the code mutch:

Use Indexes intead of string id names, so instead of

```
rowToAdd["ROW_ID"] = rowData.ROW_ID;
```

I would suggest

```
rowToAdd[0] = rowData.ROW_ID;
```

Another tip, is instead of creating the object `DataRow rowToAdd`, for every element, put the declaration of the object outside the iteration.

Also, instead of using a foreach, use a for.

Furthermore

```
var calculatedRisk = (from DataRow tradeRow in tradeTableToFilter.Rows
              where tradeRow["TradeID"] != null
              select
                  new
                      {
                          ROW_ID = 0,
                          TCN = tradeRow["TradeID"].ToString(),                               
                          CCY = tradeRow["CURRENCY"],                                 
                          USD_VALUE = calculator.Invoke(tradeRow) // configured delegate that will fetch the value
                      }).Distinct();
```

I would change this sentence all the way, instead of using such monster for one declaration of an object, I suggest doing it in baby steps, or if you have access to the data directly, use a sql sentence to filter and obtain the data.

And I would use the exact type of data, instead a generic `var`.

More complex changes would require knowing more about the code...

Comment: "Another tip, is isntead of creating the object DataRow rowToAdd, for every element, put the delcaration of the object outside the bucle." - moving the variable *declaration* does nothing with regards to performance / memory (unless you're using lamdas / anon-methods). "Also, instead of using a foreach, use a for." would need justification - this is faster for vectors, but not for most collection-types. "And I would use the exact tipe of data, instead a generic "var"." - would not change the memory usage / performance at all, and can (in some cases) change the meaning of the code.

Comment: "I would change this sentence all the way, instead of using such monster for one declaration of an object, I suggest doing it in baby steps" - meh, that's not an over-large statement; doing it as a query is actually simplifying a lot

Comment: I don't see the point of any of the suggestons you made to improve this code. Infact your suggestions make the code less flexible. Using a static value `0` instead of `ROW_ID` doesn't solve any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since (comments) you mention that you're open to the option of changing the return type, I would declare something like:

```
public class TradeRisk {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string TCN {get;set;} // expand name to be meaningful
    public string Currency {get;set;}
    public decimal UsdValue {get;set;}
}
```

and change the method to return `List<TradeRisk>`. We can apply the same `DataColumn` tricks as in my previous answer, but change the result - noting that to keep the results the same we need to preserve the `Distinct` etc.

```
var tradeId = tradeTableToFilter.Columns["TradeID"];
var currency = tradeTableToFilter.Columns["CURRENCY"];

var calculatedRisk = (from DataRow tradeRow in tradeTableToFilter.Rows
    let tradeIdVal = tradeRow[tradeId]
    where tradeIdVal != null
    select new {
        Id = 0,
        TCN = tradeIdVal.ToString(),                               
        Currency = tradeRow[currency],                                 
        UsdValue = calculator.Invoke(tradeRow)
    }).Distinct();

return (from row in calculatedRisk 
        select new TradeRisk {
            Id = row.Id, TCN = row.TCN,
            Currency = row.Currency,
            UsdValue = row.UsdValue
        }).ToList();
```

This avoid all the `DataTable` overheads. If we *really* wanted, we could also implement `TradeRisk : IEquatable<TradeRisk>`, and then just do:

```
return (
    from DataRow tradeRow in tradeTableToFilter.Rows
    let tradeIdVal = tradeRow[tradeId]
    where tradeIdVal != null
    select new TradeRisk {
        Id = 0,
        TCN = tradeIdVal.ToString(),                               
        Currency = tradeRow[currency],                                 
        UsdValue = calculator.Invoke(tradeRow)
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```